# What is the most effective way to store array from PHP to JS/jQuery so it is re-useable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

I've crushed in a problem i have never thought about. My case is that I'm making a site where the user can practice his lexical knowledge on particular language. For this reason I have a form where a foreign word is loaded and a translation input expected. Each lesson contains of 20 words.

The problem: I need to get all those words only once and somehow magically store them somewhere so my code can use this array every time the user goes on the next word.  I want to get out of connecting the database 20 times for each word.

At this point I receive the array through a ajax function in JSON format

So far I have read of the following solutions (each with its own pros and cons).

> 1.use a JS **local storage**
>
> 2.store the json in **hidden**
>
> 3.use a **global JS variable**.

What other options do I have, and which is the most suitable?

Comment: Answer depends on do you want to fetch the content again if the page is refreshed or if the browser is closed and they come back to your site?

Comment: 20 database queries isn't very much.

Comment: @epascarello lets make it easier, I'm ok if the page is refreshed and the info is lost. But still curious if i need this to be saved - whats the decision?

Comment: @Juhana - well the there is an option of loading all the words for all the lessons which is at least 1000 words. Sorry for missing this part.

Comment: Store the data in an object on the page. Reference the object. Do not over think it. :)

Comment: @epascarello yeah, thought of this but some smart people can look for the answers : )

Comment: @Alordiel If you're worried about finding the answers, keep the answer check server-side, not in JS.

Comment: @Lance Roberts thank you for correcting my English, but i can't accept your edit as they are just spelling correction. My native language is not English so i believe i'm excused for not being perfect. And anyone could explain me the down vote?

Comment: @Alordiel, spelling corrections are one of the things that we edit for.  We always try to make the posts better, which will help you get answers and maybe keep it from getting closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say your best bet would be to use JSON. Query your database once and load your results into a JSON object. From there you can use the data whenever you need it. This would be more effective than using JS variables, and also should have more support cross-browser.

Copter labs has a pretty good overview of how to use JSON:
http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/